# how to pass value from javascript to html in laravel?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I am trying to pass value from javascript to html as variable. So, I am getting value from laravel php controller.

**Javascript**

```
$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
    console.log(id);

    if(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('user.schedule.getId') }}",
            type: "GET",
            data:{'id':id},
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data) {
                console.log(data);

            }
        });
     }
});
```

**html Blade**

```
               <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs_content">
                    @foreach ($routes as $route)
                        <li >
                            <a href="#{{ $route->id }}" id="ad" data-toggle="tab">
                                {!! $route->name !!}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content blog_tabs">
                    <div class="tab-pane" name="schedule" id="" >
                        <?php
                             $tabSchedule = Schedule::
                                                where('route', $    )   
                                                ->latest()
                                                ->get();
                         ?>
                        @foreach ($tabSchedule as $schedule)
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item">{{ $schedule->schedule_number}}</li>
                            </ul>
                        @endforeach    
                    </div>
                </div>
```

So here is picture of what i want to pass and i don't know if this is possible to implement:

[image]

i want pass `data` to :

- id attirbute  (look in the above picture
- as where clause parameter in laravel php

and in case you are wondering what is value does data have is number:`1`

Comment: Do you get any error / problem ?

Comment: the thing is i am wondering if it's implentation is possible coz i don't know the answer @VincentDecaux

Comment: What data are you getting in console.log()

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
success:function(data){
 $('#tab-'+id).val(data);
}
```

Comment: how's is this suppose to pass value tabschedule where clause

Comment: @howderek after you getting data from ajax..
It passes the value to the defined id and the value gets appended to the div attribute.In this way value gets appended and every time we can get new values on ajax success.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your print values from JS to html in any HTML selector e.g :

```
$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").click(function() {
var id = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
console.log(id);

if(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('user.schedule.getId') }}",
        type: "GET",
        data:{'id':id},
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
            $("#yourDivId").text(data);
            //OR
            $("#yourDivId").val(data)

        }
    });
   }
});
```

Comment: but what if i want to pass a value to the php where clause like the picture above tells, do i need to use selector

Comment: You have to pass value via ajax to execute php code with that value.

Answer (score 0):

To change the attribute `ID`, you could simply use:

```
success:function(data){
   $('.tab-pane').attr('id', data);
}
```

To pass that attribute to your PHP script, there are many options but one of them would be adding a cookie, which stores the value of your ID attribute.

```
document.cookie= `myid=${$('.tab-pane').attr('id')}`;
```

To return the value with PHP you may use:

```
$_COOKIE['myid']
```

---

## Update

**JavaScript**

```
$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
    console.log(id);

    if(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('user.schedule.getId') }}",
            type: "GET",
            data:{'id':id},
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data) {
                $('.tab-pane').attr('id', data);
                document.cookie= `myid=${$('.tab-pane').attr('id')}`;
            }
        });
     }
});
```

**HTML Blade**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs_content">
    @foreach ($routes as $route)
    <li >
        <a href="#{{ $route->id }}" id="ad" data-toggle="tab">
            {!! $route->name !!}
        </a>
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
<div class="tab-content blog_tabs">
    <div class="tab-pane" name="schedule" id="" >
        <?php
         $tabSchedule = Schedule::
           where('route', $_COOKIE["myid"])   
           ->latest()
           ->get();
        ?>
        @foreach ($tabSchedule as $schedule)
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                {{ $schedule->schedule_number}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        @endforeach    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but could you show me how my code will look like, coz it's kinda confusing where to put your answeres

Comment: `Undefined index: myid ` is this suppose to appear

Comment: @Lafoune it may work if you refresh the page. If you don't want to refresh the page, you could use Ajax to get that cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tab plane is the handler of the click event, you can pass the data to the backend as POST data using ajax,

```
let tabId = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane')
tabId.forEach((t)={
  t.addEventListener('click', function(event, element){
    let id = element.getAttribute('id')
    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    }
  });
   $.ajax({
    url : '....', //yoururl
    method: 'POST',
    data: {'id' : id },
    success: functon(res){
      console.log(res)
    }  
  }) 
 })
})
```

then at your controller

```
public function getSchedules(Request $request){
  $id = $request->get('id');
  $schedules=Schedules::where('id', $id)->get()->toJson();
return response()->json([$schedules], 200);

}
```